# Use := in R data.table together with dynamic filter

Tags: r, data.table

How to use "dynamic" variable names in filter conditions with R's `data.table`?

Let me explain on a small example:

```
library(data.table)

X <- data.table(
  x = c("a", "b", NA),
  y = c(2, 2, 4)
)

# "Variable" variable
v <- "x"

# Replace NA in "x" by "a"
X[is.na(v), (v) := "a"]
X

# Output
      x y
1:    a 2
2:    b 2
3: <NA> 4

# Desired output
      x y
1:    a 2
2:    b 2
3:    a 4
```

Replacing `is.na(v)` by `is.na(..v)` or `is.na(!!v)` or `is.na(mget(v))` or even `is.na((v))` would not help.

Comment: `is.na(get(v))` works here.

Comment: Got me, thx! Would you mind copy pasting your comment to an answer?